# Matlab compare different sized vectors

Tags: matlab

If I have 2 vectors: A with n elements and B with m elements and m < n,

how do I identify all the elements in A which are in B, without using a for loop?

Many thanks

Answer (score 11):

`C = intersect(A,B)` will give you all the elements which are in both.

There's also `ismember(A,B)`, which will return a logical array indicating for each member of A whether it is also a member of B.

Comment: Nice, ismember is exactly what I was trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to find which elements of the longer vector (x) are in the shorter vector (y)

```
x = 1:10;
y = 2:4;

xrep = repmat(x,length(y),1)
yrep = repmat(y',1,length(x))

idx = any(xrep==yrep)
```