# MatLab - Padding arrays with something that wont be valued?

Tags: matlab, nan, pad

I'm comparing arrays of different sizes to find matches

```
Results = (DistancesB >= DistancesA * 0.1 & DistancesB < DistancesA * 1.5); % anything in this thres is matched
```

the arrays need to be same size, so `padarray` with `0`.
but now the 0's are being compared and matched... 
should I do a loop to only use results > 0? 
or is there something else I can pad with? maybe `NaN`?

Comment: Well have you tried `NaN`?

Comment: how do you pad with nan?
featuresA = padarray(DataSet2,size(MaxArray) - size(DataSet2),'post');

Comment: just don't use `padarray`, do it manually

Comment: when i say im comparing arrays i mean comparing one array to over 200 others that would take ages and not be very robust

Comment: See my answer, when I manually I just mean code out the same logic that padarray uses. For 1D arrays it's trivial.

Comment: It may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065627/matlab-compare-different-sized-vectors

Answer (score 4):

I always recommend to read the documentation. For instance, [`padarray()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/padarray.html) can pad with `NaN`:

```
padarray(1:3,[1,1],NaN,'post')
ans =
     1     2     3   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

For more details check out the description for *padval* in the link to the documentation.

Comment: +1 Not sure how I missed that as I specifically went to the docs looking for it, haha.

Comment: @Dan I would personally go with your manual suggestion to avoid the overhead of padarray, but sometimes being such a purist doesn't pay off.

Comment: Yeah, `padarray` is nice for padding 2D arrays. For 1D it does seem unnecessary. But if you've got the toolbox, and performance isn't a critical issue then it does make for very readable code.

Comment: is this correct?
NaNArray1 = padarray(DataSet,size(MaxArray)- size(DataSet),NaN, 'post');

Answer (score 2):

To pad array with `NaN`

First create vectors of only `NaN` that are as long as the longest vector:

```
PaddedA = NaN(max(length(A), length(B)), 1);
PaddedB = NaN(max(length(A), length(B)), 1);
```

Then fill these with the data. The shorter vector will now be padded with `NaN` at the end:

```
PaddedA(1:length(A)) = A;
PaddedB(1:length(B)) = B;
```

Comment: ok you were missing a bracket on first 2 lines of code and i think i placed it in wrong place?

Comment: I believe your syntax was not valid so I edited it. @Tom it should work now.

Comment: Thanks @DennisJaheruddin, that was pretty blind of me!